# IntelliJ IDEA NoClassDefFoundError - AbstractExpectedPatterns

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I got this weird exception suddenly. My API test was running OK. It is just simple rest-assured and cucumber test. The full exception log at below, I don't even know where it is coming here as it seems nothing to do with my source code. Any input is welcome. Thank you.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/rt/execution/testFrameworks/AbstractExpectedPatterns
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvmSMConverter.handleTestStepFinished(CucumberJvmSMConverter.java:97)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvm3SMFormatter$6.receive(CucumberJvm3SMFormatter.java:50)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvm3SMFormatter$6.receive(CucumberJvm3SMFormatter.java:47)
at cucumber.runner.AbstractEventPublisher.send(AbstractEventPublisher.java:45)
at cucumber.runner.AbstractEventBus.send(AbstractEventBus.java:9)
at cucumber.runner.TimeServiceEventBus.send(TimeServiceEventBus.java:3)
at cucumber.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:59)
at cucumber.runner.PickleStepTestStep.run(PickleStepTestStep.java:43)
at cucumber.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:46)
at cucumber.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:49)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime$1.run(Runtime.java:82)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(Runtime.java:217)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:79)
at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:26)
at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.rt.execution.testFrameworks.AbstractExpectedPatterns
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 24 more
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the bug of IntelliJ IDEA. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-210403

As a workaround, try to change 'Shorten command line' in Run configuration to 'JAR Manifest'

Comment: HI @Konstantin, thanks for the reply, but 'shorten command line' doesn't fix the issue. The test still failed with same error.

Comment: Is it cucumber test? Is it possible to share a sample project? Can you attach it to the bug request on YouTrack?

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply, and I can't share an example project as I'm working on company project. But it is a simple API testing with cucumber and Rest-Assured. I will leave a comment on that issue ticket.